# R Package installed but cannot be loaded?

Tags: r, install.packages

I installed the "digest" package in R.

```
> install.packages("digest")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-03-15/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/digest_0.6.12.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 172746 bytes (168 KB)
downloaded 168 KB

package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaMPhK6\downloaded_packages
```

I confirmed that this package is installed in:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\library\digest
```

My repos are:

```
getOption("repos")

                                            CRAN                                        CRANextra 
"https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-03-15"             "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"
```

Then I wanted to install "kableExtra" package. But I am getting an error message that the there is no "digest":

```
 > library(kableExtra)
    Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
      there is no package called ‘digest’
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘kableExtra’
```

What is wrong? Is this due to the fact that the original library is from CRAn, but for some reason this "digest" package is coming from MRAN? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you load `digest` by itself via `library(digest)`?

Comment: This already happened to me once or twice, I deleted the old package version directory manually.