# RStudio package "digest" cannot be used, loaded, or installed

Tags: rstudio, install.packages, quanteda

trying to follow the `quanteda` tutorial, I'm running into problems [here](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/statistical-analysis/) with the programme; executing the following code, I get error messages hinting at problems with packages I cannot resolve.

```
> require(quanteda)
> require(quanteda.corpora)
> require(ggplot2)

> corp_tweets <- download(url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/846skn1i5elbnd2/data_corpus_sampletweets.rds?dl=1')


Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘digest’
```

As the package seems to be missing, I tried loading it and get:

```
> require("digest")
Loading required package: digest
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘digest’
```

Now, I try *installing* it - again, without success.

```
> install.packages("digest")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/digest_0.6.20.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 223139 bytes (217 KB)
downloaded 217 KB

package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpaunnzu\downloaded_packages
```

Does anyone know how to take it from here? Help is much appreciated.

P.S.: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494336/r-package-installed-but-cannot-be-loaded) (unanswered) question did not help me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "solution" I could find was to re-install `RStudio`.